# How can i execute a worker service once in .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, background-service, .net-core-3.0

I'm using a service worker template in .net core 3.0 . 
What i would like to do is execute this service only once if my parameter "ExecuteOnce" is set to true
in the appsettings.json .

Program.cs :

```
public class Program
    {
        public static IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                {
                    if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    else
                        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
    }
```

Worker.cs :

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken); ;
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Bit of logic here...

                if (_configuration.GetValue<bool>("TaskConfig:ExecuteOnce"))
                    // TODO HERE : stop this service
                else
                    await Task.Delay(_configuration.GetValue<int>("TaskConfig:TaskDelayMs"), new CancellationToken());
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried : 
-awaiting a Task.TaskCompleted
-breaking the loop
-calling StopAsync()

But each time i've stumbled upon some limitations , what is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you just want the service to run, do something and exit if ExecuteOnce is true.  This is not a correct design for a service.  A service is supposed to run longer, and expect some interaction with other systems / apps / services.  What you need to do you can easily do with a simple app that you schedule for a single execution.

Comment: @Nick I don't think that's necessarily valid. For example, you might have an application that can do it's own scheduling or can be run via an external scheduler. Rather than having two code-bases, you might want to implement it the way the OP is asking.

Comment: @RB, a service should not exit just like that.  A service is supposed to be controlled by SCM.  If a service quits by itself, it is normally accepted as error.

Comment: @Nick Not necessarily - consider a service where the SCM isn't Service Control Manager, but is Kubernetes or similar. Maybe you want to start the service based on some external event (a github commit, or whatever), and have it run once then close. I mean, I agree with you that it's unusual, but I don't think it's fair to say it's wrong.

Comment: @RB, you still miss the point where it is in the nature of a service that its life is controlled _externally_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) - with this you can tell your application to shut itself down.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostLifetime;

    public Worker(IHostApplicationLifetime hostLifetime) 
    {
        _hostLifetime = hostLifetime;    
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DoWork();
            if (RunOnlyOnce())
            {
                _hostLifetime.StopApplication();
            }
        }
    }
}
```